# A function to join two arrays (m,n) to produce an mn array without any side effects

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I have two arrays of size m & n respectively

Array 1: (Say a list of users and

```
[
{fName: 'John', lname:'Doe', phone:'303-823-3234'},
{fName: 'Jane', lname:'Doe', phone:'702-919-7408'},
//and so on...
]
```

Array 2: (Say a list of roles that all users must be part of but are separated out intentionally.

```
[
{role:'All Users', description: 'All users must be part of this role},
{role:'Email', description: 'All users must have access to an email and so are part of this role'}
//and so on...
]
```

I need to merge these two arrays to build something like this

Result Array:

```
[
{fName: 'John', lname:'Doe', phone:'303-823-3234', role:'All Users', description: 'All users must be part of this role},
{fName: 'John', lname:'Doe', phone:'303-823-3234', {role:'Email', description: 'All users must have access to an email and so are part of this role'}},

{fName: 'Jane', lname:'Doe', phone:'702-919-7408', role:'All Users', description: 'All users must be part of this role},
{fName: 'Jane', lname:'Doe', phone:'702-919-7408', {role:'Email', description: 'All users must have access to an email and so are part of this role'}},
//and so on...
]
```

Here's my first approach (Say Approach 1) to abide by the Functional programming principles (i.e no side effects).

```
//x & y are Array 1 and Array 2 respectively
joinArrays: function(x, y){
    x.map(function(user){
         return  y.map(function(role){
                  return Object.assign({}, role, x); //Based on comments
              })
    }
}
```

But I think that the complexity of this can be further reduced by the following algorithm

Here's  another approach (Say Approach 2)

```
Duplicate each item of the the first array (x) by the size of y (y.length). Say the result is z //Somehow create a new array that duplicates the "references" of each ele in x.
Iterate through z. From zero to y.length*1, copy over properties of y[0] to each object. 
    And then from y.length*1+1 to y.length*2, copy over properties of y[1] to each object. And so on...
```

> Approach 1 has O(mn) time complexity. (Space complexity??, What about the
> complexity of Object.assign and the JS mapper fns?)
>
> Aproach 2's complexity: O(mn)+ O(mn)= O(mn)?? (Space complexity is higher?)

Any comments on complexity and any other solutions (functional only) that fare better?

Comment: complexity mn + mn is O(mn) so you have the same time complexity in both cases

Comment: maybe search for "cartesian product" since it is what you are doing

Comment: Perhaps it's only pseudo code, but the current implementation of approach 1 does have side effects, the roles themselves are altered. Maybe something like `return Object.assign({}, role, user);` was needed?

Comment: @Me.Name Good point!

Comment: I find your resulting data structure odd. You kind of end up with duplicated values. Just a suggestion, but why don't just change your structure and for example add an `id` prop to each role, these ids can than be added to a `roles` prop of each user obj as an array ? That would make it really simple to glue them together. [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfjtozzc/1/)

Comment: @DavidDomain I agree. It is odd because of the existing Interface contract . The service ( REST API URL Mapping) only accepts data from the client (Browser) in that format. I do have some  control and if there's a small change that simplifies the solution of this significantly,  I can make that on the Service's URL mapping. The service currently behave  this way because the data is ultimately persisted in a NoSQL store (So the data is de-normalized intentionally)

Comment: @DavidDomain Checked your fiddle. So nice to be able to use ES6!!

Comment: @user6123723 `Object.assign` is ES6, which is what you are using in your example code.

Comment: @DavidDomain Just realized that. I'm on Extjs 6.2 but since we run it on Chrome, I guess I can use ES6 for all non-Extjs JS functions I write. Good to know